# how to do if check between Carbon now and column expired_at

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

hello i need to do check after 24 hours from user created check if the user pay many or not if the user not payment set status = 0 ...  but  i cant make Comparison between time in column expired_at  and time now after 24 hours how can i do this?

```
public function handle()
{
    $update_row = booking_ravs::all();

    foreach ($update_row as $item) {

        if (Carbon::now() > $item->expired_at) {
            DB::table('booking_ravs')->update(['stauts' => 0]);
        }
    }
}
```

I try multiple if  but it doesn't work what the selection

Comment: The query you have will update **all** the rows status field to 0.

Comment: yes ..any user not pay many make status set 0

Comment: The line `DB::table('booking_ravs')->update(['stauts' => 0])` will update **all** rows. Not just the ones that haven't paid. You also have a type in your condition "stauts".

Comment: Did the below answer you question or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields are Carbon instances you can simply add the time to them:

```
(now() > $item->expired_at->addHours(24))
```

alternatively

```
(now() > $item->expired_at->addDay())
```

For more information please have a look at the [Carbon Documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub)

Comment: Carbon also has nice `isAfter()` and `isBefore()` methods.